# Make bootstrap divs NON-responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

http://codepen.io/toymechqm/pen/qOPRqp

I have  tic-tac-toe board that is too responsive. I believe the offending code is somewhere in here:

```
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

              <div class="box" id="A"></div>
              <div class="box" id="B"></div>
              <div class="box" id="C"></div>
              <div class="box" id="D"></div>
              <div class="box" id="E"></div>
              <div class="box" id="F"></div>
              <div class="box" id="G"></div>
              <div class="box" id="H"></div>
              <div class="box" id="I"></div>

          </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
```

If you look at the codepen the board is TOO responsive. It even changes when the window is too large. I would like the minimum/maximum window size to stay a tic-tac-toe board. I've played around with the documentation and fluid options. Is there some simple css to use to keep it all tied together?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Comment: Maybe using your own classes and just use media queries where needed to keep things looking clean and normal on smaller screen devices?

Comment: I don't think that that documentation applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as adding another div with a set width will help with your issue:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div style="width: 500px;">
                <div class="box" id="A"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="B"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="C"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="D"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="E"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="F"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="G"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="H"></div>
                  <div class="box" id="I"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is all that I needed

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap containers, rows, and cols are responsive in nature.  There are two ways to approach this.

1) Put your .box elements in a fixed width container and remove the responsive col-md-6.

OR

2) Make your .box elements responsive to resize with the existing container.